# Using Ternary operator to pass a parameter in spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

I wish to know if there is a way of passing a parameter conditionally while defining a spring bean. More specifically, I am trying to create a util:map with two entries, the entries are dependent on system properties as defined below:

```
 <util:map id="queryParameterMap">
    <entry key="startDate" value="${startdate}"/>
    <entry key="endDate" value="${enddate}"/>
</util:map>
```

if the system parameter is not set, the value in the map should be defaulted to null. 
How can this be done? I have tried using spring expression language but that was not of much help.

Regards,
Daya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `#{systemProperties['enddate']}`? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks... this worked... I would still like to get a better grip on spEL.... any resources that I could check?

Comment: @The Idler: I guess there is nothing better than the reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` probably has the option to set unresolved properties to null. Apart from that, SpEL supports supports defaults. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to do something like this:

<entry key="endDate" value="#{systemProperies['enddate']=='null'?null:systemProperties['enddate']"/>

that is when the enddate is present but initialized to 'null' .... how else can I use spEL for this?