# Ternary operator in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-el

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750551/using-ternary-operator-to-pass-a-parameter-in-spring-configuration). Since that question is quite old so thought of posting new question.

I am also writing my expression in following

```
<property name="to" value="#{ systemProperties['BR']} == '01' ? 
    ${PROPERTY_VALUE_1_FROM_BUNDLE} : 
    ${PROPERTY_VALUE_2_FROM_BUNDLE}" />
```

When I fetch the value of "to" variable from my bean. Its giving me something like below

```
01='01'? value1 : value2
```

Its not parsing my expression in XML itself.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are terminating the SpEL too early; it should be...

```
<property name="to" value="#{ systemProperties['BR'] == '01' ? 
    '${PROPERTY_VALUE_1_FROM_BUNDLE}' : 
    '${PROPERTY_VALUE_2_FROM_BUNDLE}' }" />
```

Note that you also need single quotes around the placeholders so the resolved values are treated as literals.

Comment: I tried this too but getting something like "EL1043E:(pos 62): Unexpected token.  Expected 'colon(:)' but was 'bean_ref(@)'"

Comment: Try adding single quotes around the `${...}` properties - `'${PROPERTY_VALUE_1_FROM_BUNDLE}'`.

Comment: Thanks @Gary, its working. So, could you please update your first answer so that I could mark it as "Accepted" :)

Comment: @GaryRussell, how should I write this expression ${gl.path}#{jobExecutionContext['refDate']} in ternary operator. Is it '${gl.path}#{jobExecutionContext['refDate']}' ?

Comment: Don't ask new questions on 7 year old answers; also, code is hard to read in comments; ask a completely new question with more context.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it using below code

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
String toMail = parser.parseExpression(to).getValue(String.class);
```

Had to make little here and there in XML but its responding as I wanted it to. Now I am getting either value in my "to" variable.